# Find length of the path in a tree to a certain element

Tags: haskell

I have tried this:

```
tWLength  (Node v l r) u            | v == u = 0
                                    | v <  u = 1 + (tWLength l)
                                    | v >  u = 1 + (tWLength r)
```

However it returns (in WinGHCi):

```
experiments\treetest.hs:170:1: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 ~ a -> a1
      Expected type: Tree a -> a1
        Actual type: Tree a -> a -> a1
    • Relevant bindings include
        tWLength :: Tree a -> a1 (bound at experiments\treetest.hs:170:1)
    |
170 | tWLength  (Node v l r) u            | v == u = 0
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

The tree is defined as:

```
data Tree a = NullTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
```

Comment: Maybe give your function a type signauter, to give us some hint of what you were thinking. What is u and why does it have the same type as v and why is it `Comparable`?

Comment: It should give one the length of a walk to a certain thing in a tree.

Comment: What if the thing you want to find is not in a tree?

Comment: @jpath, I don't know what `Comparable` is. Purescript? Scala? It's not a standard or well-known Haskell class. Without a type signature, an `Ord` constraint will be inferred once the error is corrected.

Comment: @MarkNeu, in the future, please give much more information in your questions. You should have explained that the tree is a *binary search tree*. You should have explained that your function is supposed to find the length of the path to a particular element (trees don't necessarily have "lengths" in general). You can often get more useful type errors by giving your functions type signatures, but in this case you actually got quite a good error message; you just need to get used to reading them.

Comment: Separately, you should probably make your function return `Maybe Int` (or whichever numeric type you want) to deal gracefully with the case where the element is not found.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, I meant `Ord`. I don't know any language that has `Comparable` actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found the reason. I was calling `tWLength` with only one argument in

```
tWLength  (Node v l r) u        | v == u = 0
                                | v <  u = 1 + (tWLength l)
                                | v >  u = 1 + (tWLength r)
```

when it should have been

```
tWLength  (Node v l r) u        | v == u = 0
                                | v <  u = 1 + (tWLength l u)
                                | v >  u = 1 + (tWLength r u)
```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem He's looking for the length of the path from the root to `u`, not the size of the tree.